# Positioning Tikz over a table line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a custom CV class with a job history timeline. Specifically, I would like a black dot over the table line next to the title. I've tried to do this with Tikz, but it isn't quite working as expected (see MWE).

There is probably a more elegant way to do this. Does anyone know how?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\tabledot}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \filldraw[black] (2.4,0.86) circle (.5ex) node[] {};         
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \newcommand{\expitem}[4]{
        \tabledot
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.8\linewidth}}
            #1 & \textbf{#2}\\
            & \textit{#3}\\
            & {\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont #4}
        \end{tabular}
    }
\expitem{1998-1999}{Experimental Assistant, Black Mesa Research Labs}{Anomalous Materials Laboratory}{My work here consists of little more than pressing a button and pushing a cart. Please, someone give me a job working in theoretical physics.}
\expitem{1992-1997}{PhD Theoretical Physics, MIT}{Supervised by Dr. Isaac Kleiner}{Thesis Title: Observation of Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Entanglement on Supraquantum Structures by Induction Through Nonlinear Transuranic Crystal of Extremely Long Wavelength (ELW) Pulse from Mode-Locked Source Array}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following
[image]

How can I make the second dot line up properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a minimal damage proposal that puts the bullet next to the date in `overlay` mode. There are certainly cleaner ways to do this.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\expitem}[4]{
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.8\linewidth}}
            \tikz[baseline={(X.base)}]{\node[inner sep=0pt](X){#1};
            \fill[overlay] (X.west)+(2.12,0) circle[radius=.5ex];} & \textbf{#2}\\
            & \textit{#3}\\
            & {\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont #4}
        \end{tabular}
    }
\expitem{1998-1999}{Experimental Assistant, Black Mesa Research Labs}{Anomalous Materials Laboratory}{My work here consists of little more than pressing a button and pushing a cart. Please, someone give me a job working in theoretical physics.}
\expitem{1992-1997}{PhD Theoretical Physics, MIT}{Supervised by Dr.\ Isaac Kleiner}{Thesis Title: Observation of Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Entanglement on Supraquantum Structures by Induction Through Nonlinear Transuranic Crystal of Extremely Long Wavelength (ELW) Pulse from Mode-Locked Source Array}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.